# Free software for creating fMRI film paradigm

Tags: video-editor, editing

I'm looking for an intuitive, user-friendly software that will allow me to cut sections from videos downloaded on Youtube, combine them into a single video, and insert still pictures between some of these videos that will be displayed for 1, 3, 5 or 25 seconds.  The end of the video will include 10 pictures, each displayed for about 3-5 seconds.

I have a Mac and have iMovie but haven't had much luck with it so far.  It doesn't even show the time for the clips when you put the cursor somewhere.

So I'm looking for a program that would allow any idiot to make they type of video I described above.  I'm a neuroscientist, not a video editor!! haha

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you are looking for a software, this better fits on [softwarerecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).